# phpMyAdmin does and doesn't run my stored procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I have a stored procedure (on a mysql server) and it depends how I try to run it as to whether or not it works.  Which really doesn't make sense.

In phpMyAdmin if I go to the tree view (left side of window) and click on the stored procedure, it'll prompt me for the parameters and it'll run and return a result everything is OK.  Not only is there a result, it is also correct.

However if in phpMyAdmin I go to the SQL window and type in Call get_houses(1, 1) it fails and there is no result and no error message.  (Note: the values of the parameters is the same.)(Also note: the correct database is selected.)

Also the php I have written doesn't return any value either.

What on earth is going on?  Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: What version of phpMyAdmin are you using?

Comment: Database server

    Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
    Server type: MySQL
    Server version: 5.5.41-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 - (Ubuntu)
    Protocol version: 10
    User: admin@localhost
    Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Comment: Some versions of phpMyAdmin have a bug in which stored procedures run in unexpected ways (or not at all). You can find your phpMyAdmin version in the interface itself (usually at the bottom), or by consulting your package manager (if you installed it as a package) or by opening the source files themselves.

Comment: phpMyAdmin

    Version information: 4.2.5

Answer (score 0):

According to information in comments, you are using phpMyAdmin version 4.2.5 which contained [this bug](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/history/blob/master/ChangeLogs/ChangeLog-2014#L154):

> bug #4404 Recordset return from procedure display nothing

The bug is fixed in version 4.2.12, so consider upgrading to the latest version to get access to the fix.

Other clients, such as MySQL Workbench or the command-line MySQL client, are not affected by this bug.